When setting property IconLocation of IWshShortcut it appends ",0" to the end of the string
I have this method...
        private static void InsertShortcut(string shortcutPath, string shortcutName)
        {
            List<string>? files = [.. Directory.GetFiles(shortcutPath)];

            if (files.Find(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).Contains(shortcutName)) != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            WshShell wsh = new WshShell();

            IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut shortcut = wsh.CreateShortcut(shortcutPath + $"\\{shortcutName}.lnk") as IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut;

            shortcut.TargetPath = $"\"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\FileManager.exe\"";
            shortcut.Arguments = $" \"{shortcutPath}\"";
            shortcut.Description = "Shortcut to run FileManager.exe with relative path as arg";
            shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

            //Not sure about what this is for
            shortcut.WindowStyle = 1;

            //When setting IconLocation it automatically appends ",0" to the end of it!!!???
            shortcut.IconLocation = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\..\\..\\..\\Images\\FileManagerIcon.png";
            shortcut.Save();
        }

It sets the properties of a shorcut and creates the shortcut.
When I set the IconLocation to the location of my icon, the value of "shortcut.IconLocation"in the debug window shows as:
C:\Users\<user>\Desktop\Project\FileManager\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\..\..\..\Images\FileManagerIcon.png,0
As you can see it appends a ",0" to the end of the string, does anyone know why it does this? And how to get around it.
I'm currently using .Net 8 on Windows 10.

I think the 'IconLocation' property needs to be set to an icon resource, not directly to an image file. So for example, the path to the exe if it contains an icon resource, and the suffix you are seeing would be the index inside that resource. So I think this means you need a .ico, .exe or .dll

Note, you can try this yourself by using the Windows UI to try and associate a new icon with a shortcut, just see what you can choose.

@DavidG Yes you are correct, after some further research the IconLocation takes the path to a .dll containing icons of certain type (not sure what type). The ,0 is the index of the icon to use.
This is what I've done, shortcut.IconLocation = @"%SystemRoot%\System32\SHELL32.dll,110";
